# Providing a Sequence as a parameter to a method accepting varargs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In the `Spark` `DataFrame` we have a `select` method that has a `varargs` second parameter:

```
  @scala.annotation.varargs
  def select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame = 
        select((col +: cols).map(Column(_)) : _*)
```

I would like to invoke the `select` using a `Sequence`:

```
val ProductCols = Seq("prdct_id", "prdct_tag")
```

The preference would be to invoke as follows:

```
myDataFrame.select(ProductCols: _*)
```

However that does not resolve to the method shown above, so the following has been used:

```
myDataFrame.select(ProductCols.head, ProductCols.tail: _*)
```

Is there a way to send the `ProductCols` only once - and the `varargs` would accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap String to column:

```
 Df.select(cols.map(x => col(x)) :_*)
```

Write also `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

Comment: That seems to be a useful direction: need to add `:_*` to make it work. And more concisely:  `map(col):_*`

Comment: @javadba Yes :) I wrote it in tram and didn't check